# Umbraco 7 UmbracoAuthorizedApiController returns 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm creating a custom tree inside umbraco7 and and have a button which will call an `UmbracoAuthorizedApiController` called ExportApiController i added a constructor and set a breakpoint on it to see if this controller is indeed instanced and it is. But when i try to call the call my action it is returning an 405 (Method Not Allowed)

And in the response i see the following text

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

above my controller action i have the `HttpGet` attribute and i also tried the put or post but nothing helps. But i think that when i use post i need to do something else inside Angular to call it using a submit on a form? But i'm not sure how or why.

If you need more information please tell me and i will post it.

Thanks.

Comment: No one that can comment on this? I'm pretty sure i'm not the only one that is trying to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and for me the problem was that I accidently had `HttpGetAttribute.HttpGet` instead of `System.Web.Http.HttpGet`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your method ? I find that if you don't actually have "get" in the front of the name it would throw out this error so 
public string CorrectTime(string time)  < -- would fail but 
public string GetCorrectTime(string time) <-- would pass

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to export data, I guess you are trying to use this controller for the big public.  However, `UmbracoAuthorizedApiController` are only for back-end users as mentioned in the [documentation](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/authorization).  You should not use these to expose data outside the Umbraco back-end.

If you want to expose data, and you want to validate against the members (not users) you should prefix your [UmbracoApiController](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/webapi/) with the [MemberAuthorize attribute](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/authorization)

Comment: Hi dampee, this is not the thing. I use the `UmbracoAuthorizedApiController` from within the backend. the User (not member) needs to be logged in and is logged in. I have another controller which is just doing fine but this one isn't, so i was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: If another controller is doing fine, you will need to add more information to your question.